Getting an authentication error during storage account role assignment for managed identity
I am getting an error while assigning role to managed identity in storage account RBAC
Code:
RoleAssignmentCreateOrUpdateContent roleData = new RoleAssignmentCreateOrUpdateContent(
roleDefinitionId: new ResourceIdentifier(string.Concat("/subscriptions/", 
SubscriptionId, "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/", roleId)),
principalId: (Guid)userIdentity.PrincipalId
)
{
PrincipalType = RoleManagementPrincipalType.ServicePrincipal
};

ArmOperation<RoleAssignmentResource> roleAssignmentOperation =
roleCollection.CreateOrUpdateAsync(
WaitUntil.Completed,
Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
roleData
).GetResult();

This is the error I am geting
ERROR: System.Exception: The client 'xxx' with object id
'xxx' does not have authorization to perform action 
'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write' over scope '/subscriptions/xxx
/resourceGroups/name/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/name/providers
/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/xxx' or the scope is invalid.
If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.
ERROR: Status: 403 (Forbidden)
ERROR: ErrorCode: AuthorizationFailed


To resolve the error, you need to assign User Access Administrator role or Owner role to the client to assign the role


The client 'xxx' with object id 'xxx' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write' over
scope '/subscriptions/xxx /resourceGroups/name/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/name/providers /Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/xxx' or the scope is invalid

The error usually occurs if the user or client doesn't have required roles to perform the action.
To assign storage account role assignment for managed identity, the user or the client must have User Access Administrator role or Owner role.
To resolve the error, in your case try to assign one of the roles to the client (The client 'xxx' with object id 'xxx'):
Go to Azure Portal -> Subscriptions -> Select your subscription -> Add -> Add role assignment -> Select Privileged administrator roles -> User Access Administrator

Assign role to the user that is (The client 'xxx' with object id 'xxx'):

After assigning the role, you will be able to assign storage account role assignment for managed identity.
